# How to delete item in nested list if it contains keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists. The list named "keyword" is a list I manually created, and the nested list named "mylist" is an output of a function that I have in my script. This is what they look like:

```
keyword = ["Physics", "Spanish", ...]

mylist = [("Jack","Math and Physics"), 
          ("Bob","English"), 
          ("Emily","Physics"), 
          ("Mark","Gym and Spanish"),
          ("Brian", "Math and Gym"),
          ...]
```

What I am trying to do is delete each item in the nested list if that item (in parenthesis) contains *any* of the keywords written in the "keyword" list.

For example, in this case, any items in "mylist" that contain the words "Physics" or "Spanish" should be deleted from "mylist". Then, when I print "mylist", this should be the output:

```
[("Bob","English"), ("Brian", "Math and Gym")]
```

I tried searching through the internet and many different SO posts to learn how to do this (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790072/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-that-contains-words-found-in-items-in-another-li?lq=1)), but when I modify (because I have a nested list, instead of just a list) the code and run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "namelist.py", line 165, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(request1())
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 576, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "namelist.py", line 154, in request1
    mylist.remove(a)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error, and could you share your code?

**EDIT:** By the way, the real "mylist" I have on my script is much longer than what I wrote here, and I have about 15 keywords. When I run it on a small scale like this, the code works well, but as soon as I have more than 5 keywords, for some reason, I keep getting this error.

Comment: I assume you only care if any of the words in the second item in a tuple are a keyword, but you should probably be explicit about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could join each of the tuples into a string and then check if any keyword is in the string to filter your list.

```
newlist = [m for m in mylist if not any(k for k in keywords if k in ' '.join(m))]

print(newlist)
# [('Bob', 'English'), ('Brian', 'Math and Gym')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in keyword:
  for tup in mylist:
    [mylist.remove(tup) for i in tup if key in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by splitting the fields with `and` and looking at intersection between the keys and the fields of each person. For instance, you could imagine something like this:

```
new_list = []

for name,fields in mylist:
    # Convert the string into a set of string for intersection
    field_set = set(fields.split(" and "))
    field_in_keys = field_set.intersection(keyword)

    # Add in the new list if no intersection is found
    if len(field_in_keys) == 0:
        new_list.append((name,fields))
```

You get:

```
[('Bob', 'English'), ('Brian', 'Math and Gym')]
```

If you care for speed, then [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) might do the work more efficiently

Comment: This works great for my example, however, I think benvc's answer is a little bit more robust since it doesn't specifically require the word "and" to be in the list. Thanks for the answer though, upvoted!

Comment: I prefer `if not field_in_keys` instead of `if len(field_in_keys) == 0` here.

Answer (score 1):

```py
for x in keyword:
    for i in mylist:
        for w in i[1].split(' '):
            if w == x:
                mylist.remove(i)
```

If you just loop through each word I think that will work as well.